# My previously working facebook script now getting OAuthException Code 1 error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a php script that is using the following Facebook api call:

$apicall = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$page}?access_token={$fbappid}|{$fbappsecret}";

This has been working fine for a long time and getting me data... but since yesterday all I am getting is:

{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

Nothing has changed on my end, so I don't understand what the problem is.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your access token from Facebook may have expired. I suggest going to the dev website again and requesting a new access token.

Comment: Ok, I will try that but I just found this as well: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like it is the issue posted at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/

I got it to work again using the following:

$apicall = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$page}?fields={$fields_I_need}&access_token={$fbappid}|{$fbappsecret}";